# Trouble updating Office 2011 on an old MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office, software-update

My uncle (who is not a tech-savvy person) has owned an Apple laptop for a long time. He bought Office 2011 products a few years ago. He has now asked me to take a look at Office asking him to update to a newer version. It's a MacBook Pro (Retina 13", End 2012), with macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

His Office is on version 14.4.2. I tried running the updater, but it states that it cannot connect to the update server - I'm assuming that is the case because Microsoft has stopped support for Office 2011.

When trying to download updates manually (I downloaded 14.7.7, which I think is the latest one?), the installer says that the update requires a version of office that is not installed.

And while this might sound stupid, I cannot find a list of official updates for the software such that I could install them one by one.

I would appreciate advice on this. I'm really unfamiliar with Macs which makes this a bit more difficult even though it seems like a simple problem.

Furthermore, my uncle keeps getting an error message when he closes office documents, gets asked to save, clicks on save. The document gets saved but Word somehow crashes. I've told him to just press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> before closing, which does solve the crashing, but he's used to just closing and then clicking save when prompted.

Does anybody know how I could get rid of this error?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you help us with the version of macOS (Operating System) running on the laptop? In the Menu bar shown on the top of the screen, click on Apple → About This Mac. It will show a dialogue box which will tell you the name and version of macOS installed along with the make and model of the MacBook just below that. This information will help in getting relevant answers quickly.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Right, I'll update that information in the post!